# ElasticSearch - Reindex to add doc_value

Tags: elasticsearch

## What am I trying to do?

Add doc_type to an existing index.

## What have I tried?

### Created index and document

```
POST /my_index-1/my_type/1
{
    "my_prop": "my_value"
}
```

### Added a template

```
PUT /_template/my_template
{
    "id": "my_template",
    "template": "my_index-*",
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "my_prop_template": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "doc_values": true,
                            "fielddata": {
                                "format": "doc_values"
                            },
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "match": "my_prop",
                        "match_mapping_type": "string"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Reindexed

```
./stream2es es --source http://localhost:9200/my_index-1 --target http://localhost:9200/my_index-2
```

## What went wrong?

In the new index `my_index-2` the property did not receive `"doc_values": true`:

```
...
"properties": {
    "my_prop": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
...
```

- Just for the sanity, I have also tried adding the same document to my_index-3, and it got `"doc_values": true`.

## My question

How can I reindex my old index with `"doc_values": true`?

Comment: Weird, I've applied the same steps in my env, the only difference is that I used logstash (with `elasticsearch` input + output) instead of stream2es and it worked out fine. What do you get when you call `curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index-2/_mapping`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Val! Logstash indeed solved the problem.

Both [stream2es](https://github.com/elastic/stream2es) and [elasticsearch-reindex](https://github.com/karussell/elasticsearch-reindex) created new mapping *without* "doc_values": true.